# When we enter the search term attachment in SOLR, we get fewer results compared to the plural term attachments. What are we missing?

Tags: solr

We would expect to get more search results using the single term, yet we are seeing just the opposite in our SOLR search results. Attachment yields fewer results than attachments. Sale yields fewer results than sales. What are we missing?

Comment: What is your field definition? this is usually handled by stemming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about different results for `sale` and `sales`. You have more results for `sales`.

Possible your question is about text corpus and tokenizer.

**text corpus**

It is not unusual to have a word in plural in a text but not in singular.

**tokenizer**

As default solr using the [standard query parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser) on field "text" with fieldtype "text_general".

You can test with the solr [analysis screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen) the way from a word (in real text) to the corresponding token in the index.

For "text_general" the word "sales" goes to "sales".
But for "text_en" the word "sales" goes to "sale".

So for fieldtype "text_en" you would get the same hits for "sales" and for "sale".

Hope this helps, otherwise post your search field and your definition from schema.xml...

Comment: Karsten, thanks so very much. We needed to get pointed in the right direction.